# php join 2 tables by date problem

Tags: mysql, join

So i have 2 tables which does not have any column in common and i want to store them by their date column

So table1 is like:

table1

- id
- post_id
- post_date

table2

- id
- comment_id
- comment_date

what i want to show is everything from table1,table2 and sort it by date

i tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ORDER BY post_date DESC, comment_date DESC
```

the problem is that i dont know how to identify which item(post or comment) i am using inside the while(rows = mysql_fetch_assoc()) since i have different column names.

Solution was:

```
                SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT 1 AS `table`, `col1` AS `userid`, `col2` AS `cat`, `col3` AS `item_id`, `title` AS `title`, etc... , `date` AS `date` FROM `table1`
                UNION
                SELECT 2 AS `table`, `col1` AS `userid`, `col2` AS `cat`, `col3` AS `item_id`, NULL AS `title`, etc... , `date` AS `date` FROM `table2`
            ) AS tb
            ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: Describe  _i dont know how to identify which item(post or comment)_

Comment: so lets say my table1 has some records, but table2 is still null...
how do i know which data to show?table1's or table2's ? since i have different columns on both tables

Comment: Your topic says that you want to join by date, but your code joins by id. This makes no sense to me. At all. What exactly do you wish to accomplish?

Comment: since i use ORDER BY post_date DESC, comment_date DESC isnt it joining the 2 tables and showing them DESC by their date?im trying to show all the records from these 2 tables DESC by date

Comment: Are the comments not related to the posts?

Comment: This code `SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ORDER BY post_date DESC, comment_date DESC` gives a cross join, not what you want :-).

Comment: i was trying to achieve it with what i know so far... and as it seems i failed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS `table`, `col1` AS `userid`, `col2` AS `cat`, `col3` AS `item_id`, `title` AS `title`, etc... , `date` AS `date` FROM `table1`
            UNION
            SELECT 2 AS `table`, `col1` AS `userid`, `col2` AS `cat`, `col3` AS `item_id`, NULL AS `title`, etc... , `date` AS `date` FROM `table2`
        ) AS tb
        ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Try a `UNION`, with a new constant column indicating which table is being output and make the column names the same using `AS`.

A surrounding `SELECT` might allow you to order it together.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT 1 AS `table`, `id`, `post_id` AS `table_id`, `post_date` AS `date` FROM `table1`)
    UNION
    (SELECT 2 AS `table`, `id`, `comment_id` AS `table_id`, `comment_date` AS `date` FROM `table2`)
)
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

That would need testing, not sure if it is allowed.

Comment: the code above doesnt work as i want, i have to assign all the columns from the 2 tables and have the same key name for example post_date=date and comment_date=date, what i want is to check from which table im getting the data each time the while loop runs(which fetches the data).

thanks anyway.

Comment: @fxuser: That is what should happen with that code.  You use the `table` field to determine origin.  The fields are unified as requested.

Comment: the thing is that on one table the columns dont actually match up with the other table and im having trouble with showing the data...
ill give a try with union

Comment: @fxuser: When you say, do not match up?  What do you mean?  If you mean there are no shared fields, then the `UNION` is what you need.  If you mean they are different datatypes, then you'll have to make some sort of conversion or have the data separate.

Comment: on table1 i need to get 9 columns to work with and on the second table i have to get 8 columns.. that means that 1 column misses from the second (SELECT).. also the columns dont share all the fields.. so i have a problem there...

Comment: @fxuser: Yes, you do have a problem there.  Why do they need to be in a single `SELECT`? The missing column is not a problem, just use `NULL AS field_name` in the required location.  `UNION` needs the same columns, in the same order - if you need extra, you need to use different fields for the separate fields, padding with `NULL` on the table that has different data.

Comment: @fxuser, no you don't, just specify a `, null as missing_field` in the select for the table with the missing field.

Comment: @fxuser: If you are still stuck, then continue to ask, show where you have got up to.  Hopefully you have solved it though.

Comment: @Orbling, i just solved it, please check my post above for the solution, thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to redesign your database if you want to link posts to comments.

*Given these tables*

```
table1

    id
    post_id
    post_date

table2

    id
    comment_id
    comment_date
```

And the fact that comments should be comments belonging to posts, you need to change the tables, so that its structure becomes:

```
table post

    id         /*id of a post*/
    user_id    /*which user posted this*/
    post_date  /*when?*/
    post_text  /*the text inside the post*/

table comments

    id            /*id of a comment*/
    post_id       /*which post does this comment belong to*/
    user_id       /*who posted this*/
    comment_date  /*when*/
    comment_text  /*text of the comment*/
```

Now you can join this by doing:

```
$post_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['post_id']);

/*select all comments belonging to a post*/
$query = "SELECT c.user_id, c.comment_date, c.comment_text FROM posts p
          INNER JOIN comments c ON (c.post_id = p.id)
          WHERE p.id = '$post_id'";
....
```

In your current design there is **no way** to reliably join them because there is no relation between the two.

Comment: i didnt make myself clear, the 2 tables are a simple example , i want to show all of them descending by the date added in the database, table1 could be links, table2 could be tas and so on , i just want tos how them descending by their date added

Comment: @fxusers, @Orbling already answered that, you should accept his answer. Still your example doesn't make any sense, homework?

Comment: its not homework, im just creating some scripts for a web app